# Modify custom entry in Info.plist

Tags: ios, xcode, info.plist

I have a custom key in Info.plist that I would like to modify during resigning. Is this possible?
I have tried unzipping the ipa and setting the value for my custom key using terminal but when I tried to side load it through iTunes, it did not install.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Modifying Info.plist invalidates the signature on the ipa. I just had to resign after modifying the file and it works now.